# Select imploded values from a database and select them in a dropdown box

Tags: php

I have the below code to generate a multiple select box with values from a database. The page in question is a form for modifying previously entered information. The value of “$Interviewers0” is retrieve before the box is generated. If the value of “$Interviewers0” is “John Doe” it selects  that name fine. But if I have a value of “John Doe, Jane Doe” none of the names are selected. I know it’s because of the imploded value but I haven’t been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

```
{
$box1 = array();
 $result = "SELECT FullName FROM UserInformation";
  $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$result);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) { $box1[] = $row; }
}
 $Interviewers = '<select name="Interviewers[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">';
  $Interviewers .= '<option>---< Select Interviewers >---</option>';
if (!empty($box1)) {foreach ($box1 as $k => $v)
 {if(!empty($Interviewers0)){$Interviewers .= '<option value="'.$v['FullName'].'"'. (!strcmp($v['FullName'],$Interviewers0)?' selected':'').'>'.$v['FullName'].'</option>';}
  else
 {$Interviewers .= '<option value="'.$v['FullName'].'">'.$v['FullName'].'</option>';}
}
}
$Interviewers .= '</select>';
echo $Interviewers;
```

Comment: I don't see any `implode()` in your code...

Comment: Learn to properly indent your code please and don't be afraid of using whitespace. Nobody is going to think you are a racist for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be done with [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

So, use:

```
(strpos($v['FullName'], $Interviewers0) !== false) ? ' selected' : ''
```

instead of:

```
!strcmp($v['FullName'],$Interviewers0)?' selected':''
```

With `(strpos($v['FullName'], $Interviewers0) !== false) ? ' selected' : ''`, if `$Interviewers0` is found in `$v['FullName']` then the `option` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
(!strcmp($v['FullName'],$Interviewers0)?' selected':'')
```

with

```
((stripos($Interviewers0, $v['FullName']) !== false) ?' selected':'')
```

and that did it.